# How to style <xe:tabBar> and <xe:tabBarButton> as a footer navigation bar in mobile?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How can I style the xe:tabBar and xe:tabBarButton control so it looks as a "native" footer with buttons (including icons, text)?

Comment: Which version of domino are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To have your tabbar stay at the bottom of the page, use a Dojo ScrollablePane (dojox.mobile.ScrollablePane). If you're using Domino 9, this widget is already available and can be implemented like:

```
<xe:appPage
id="appPage1"
pageName="firstpage">
<xe:djxmHeading
    id="heading1"
    label="Scrollable Pane Demo">
</xe:djxmHeading>
<xp:div
    id="scrollableContent"
    dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollablePane">
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="fixedFooter">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var mobFooter = getComponent("tabBar1");
return mobFooter.getClientId(facesContext);}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="fixedHeader">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var mobHeader = getComponent("heading1");
return mobHeader.getClientId(facesContext);}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="scrollDir"
                value="v">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="fixedHeaderHeight"
                value="54">
             </xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="fixedFooterHeight"
                value="54">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE
</xp:div>
<xe:tabBar
    id="tabBar1"
    barType="segmentedControl"> 
</xe:tabBar>
</xe:appPage>
```

The Header and footer must stay outside the ScrollablePane and the following dojo attributes are required for functionality:

- fixedHeader
- fixedFooter
- scrollDir
- fixedHeaderHeight
- fixedFooterHeight

If you're using Domino 8.5.3 then you will have to add the ScrollablePane and all of it's dependencies to your NSF which I cover in a blog post [here](http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=2F77016A2C3C79C686257B54006889BF). You can find additional documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a version of the dojo scrollableView or scrollablePane in order to get the navigation bar to reliably position itself at the bottom of the mobile device. Watch out for a video from Keith Strickland on NotesIn9 that explains how to do this if you have any troubles.

Using Domino 9.0 we at Red Pill Development have found that styling the NavBar with CSS alone does not guarantee the navigation bar will always drop to the bottom of the screen on each application page transition and/or screen orientation and/or partial refresh.

Answer (score -1):

This is currently not possible with the current set of XPages mobile controls. We have logged PHAN962BJ8 to address this in the future.

Comment: Paul, that's not true, the ScrollablePane (dojox.mobile.ScrollablePane) available in Domino 9 addresses this issue perfectly. Hence my question on which version of Domino.

Comment: I agree, I meant to state that it isn't possible directly and that you have to set a number of properties for configuration. The hope is that all this can be done out of the box and without having to do these extra steps.

Comment: I think from a developers stand point to expect IBM to address and provide components for everything in dojo would be expecting a lot (Even though domino developers are a spoiled lot thanks to IBM, which is a good thing I think). While it would be cool if IBM could do that, they can't possibly think of every implementation that someone might try and come up with. The developer needs to step up and find work arounds for what IBM doesn't provide as XPages and Domino provide the perfect infrastructure for that. Once devs learn there are no more limitations their skills will progress dramatically.